# Element is not appearing when hovering over another element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

When I hover over the `p1` element the `h1` element is supposed to appear but it doesn't. I am a bit confused by this because when I looked it up this is what it said to do but it doesn't seem to work.

````css
h1 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  color: white;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: none;
}

p {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

p1 {
  color: blueviolet;
}

p1:hover + h1 {
  display: block;
}

```
````

```html
<h1>Welcome to IT202</h1>
<p><strong>Mouse over the text "Show Welcome" and the welcome message is displayed. Mouse out and the welcome messages disappears!</strong></p>
<p1>Show Welcome</p1>
```

I tried adding ids but that did not work

Comment: No such thing as a `p1` element. And `+` is the [next sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Next-sibling_combinator) and the `h1` isn't the next sibling anyway

Answer (score 0):

> "When I hover over the `p1` element the `h1` element is supposed to appear but it doesn't."

False.

You're using the [next-sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Next-sibling_combinator) (`+`), which targets the following sibling.

There is no `h1` coming after a `p1` in your code. Therefore, nothing is being targeted with `p1:hover + h1`.

It works, for example, if you put the `p1` before the `h1`.

```css
h1 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  color: white;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: none;
}

p1 {
  color: blueviolet;
}

p1:hover + h1 {
  display: block;
}

p {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p1>Show Welcome</p1>
<h1>Welcome to IT202</h1>
<p><strong>Mouse over the text "Show Welcome" and the welcome message is displayed. Mouse out and the welcome messages disappears!</strong></p>
```

If you want to maintain the order of elements on the screen, consider the `order` property.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  color: white;
  width: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: none;
}

p1 {
  order: 1;
  color: blueviolet;
}

p1:hover + h1 {
  display: block;
}

p {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p1>Show Welcome</p1>
<h1>Welcome to IT202</h1>
<p><strong>Mouse over the text "Show Welcome" and the welcome message is displayed. Mouse out and the welcome messages disappears!</strong></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use  tag as HTMl does not have any  builtIn tag insted use . In css #p1:hover{backgroundcolor:red} this may resolve

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).